# NGINX proxy_pass to Redis and PostgreSQL Docker Containers

Tags: postgresql, docker, nginx, redis

I have a website which sends traffic through the user's browser to both a Redis and a PostgreSQL docker container.

In testing environment, the flask app is configured so traffic goes to:

redis://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379 and
postgresql://postgres@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:5432/table

The problem I am having is that the production environment relies on NGINX to do all of this routing, whereas in the testing environment, there is no routing and everything is just sent directly. The current NGINX proxy_pass configurations for these looks like this:

proxy_pass http:xxx.xxx.xxx:[port]

My belief is that the issue is both of these services rely on TCP instead of HTTP, yet the requests are being routed through as HTTP requests.

**So, my question is:** can I set the proxy_pass to use redis://xxx.xxx.xxx:6379 instead of http://xxx.xxx.xxx:6379? Or is this something that needs to be done in a different way? There are many other services relying on this same NGINX instance and I do not want to break anything.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can def configure NGINX to listen on port 6379 and 5432, then configure TCP proxying to the redis and postgres backends.

You just have to update your NGINX config to include server blocks for each backend service 'postgres' and 'redis' if you want to pass their traffic using tcp and not http/s.

```
stream {
    # ...
    server {
        listen     6379;
        proxy_pass XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:6379;
    }
    server {
        listen     5432;
        proxy_pass XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:5432;
    }
}
```

So in theory your app will use the `NGINX_SERVER_IP_ADDR_OR_HOSTNAME:6379` to connect to Redis and `NGINX_SERVER_IP_ADDR_OR_HOSTNAME:5432` to connect to postgres.

See documentation for more info on TCP load balancing: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/